# how to add my own status message to the tabpanel using extjs

Tags: extjs, messagebox

i am developing one project with ui as pure extjs. I am facing one problem i want to add my own status message to the tabpanel in extjs only. please help me.

Comment: are you trying to create a statu bar at the bottom of the tab panel?

Comment: where do you want to show the message, at top toolbar? at bottom bar or right side of the panel header or body of the panel?

Comment: i want to add the message on the tabpanel itself and its on right side of the tabpanel

Comment: @ Abdel Olakara not on the bottom actually i want to add my own message on the tabpanel as a status message

Answer (score 0):

Each Component extending Ext.Panel accepts a config option called `bbar` which is the bottom Ext.Toolbar. this can function as a statusbar for your TabPanel if you want to. Check the docs on [Ext.Panel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Panel) and [Ext.Toolbar](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Toolbar) for more info.

```
new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Basic StatusBar',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'a button',
    }],
    bbar: ['->', 'Status bar']
});
```

If you are looking for more functionality you could also check out the official [Statusbar Extension](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/ux/statusbar/StatusBar.js) which you can find the official [ExtJS Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/statusbar/statusbar-demo.html) on sencha.com

Comment: thank you for this but actually i need it on the tabpanel itself i mean i want to add my status message on the tabpanel itself on the rightside of tabpanel

Comment: where do you need it now? On the tabpanel or on the right of the tabpanel and what do you actually mean by statusmessage?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it from Firebug console an ExtJS included page. It is not a good way for this but, achieves your need.

```
// this function should be in a namespace as a method
var updateStatusMessage = function(msg){
    var msgEl = document.getElementById('tabPanelStatusMessage');
    if (msgEl) {
        msgEl.innerHTML = msg;
    }
    // style rules of span should be given with a css class 
    return Ext.DomHelper.createDom({tag:'span', id:'tabPanelStatusMessage', style: 'position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px', html: msg })
}
new Ext.Window({
    title: 'test window',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    items: {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        activeTab: 0,
        id: 'statusTabPanel',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'test',
                html: 'this is a demo tab panel item'
            }
        ]
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            Ext.select('#statusTabPanel .x-tab-strip-wrap').appendChild(updateStatusMessage('Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'))
        }
    }
}).show();

// you can call updateStatusMessage function with a message to update the message
```